# How to upgrade dockerized Jira to the latest version without downtime

Tags: docker, deployment, ansible, jira

We have deployed Jira in our Docker swarm cluster and it is running fine. We are planning to upgrade  to the latest version. Is it possible to upgrade to the latest version without downtime.

From My understanding, it is not possible as the database need to be upgraded and dbconfig.xml need to be changed as per the version.

Comment: Your database is mounted correctly? If it is so, you can use Kubernetes to give you zero downtime on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with docker container are that you should really not persist any data within, unless you mount volumes. If you did then stopping (docker-compose down & docker-compose up -d) should work.
Else - try to copy your db files to host machine (with docker cp) and change your docker-compose to use volumes with this files.